# exception while trying to deploy liferay portlet with spring

Tags: java, spring, liferay, javabeans

I'm trying to create a portlet with liferay 6.2 and using spring. If I create a bean without using constructor-arg or factory-method then everything works fine. But if I use either of these then I get exceptions when the portlet is deployed.
an example:

the exception I'm getting is:

01:28:21,884 ERROR [ContextLoader:323] Context initialization failed
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

I realize that this can be caused by having 2 versions of ams, but im using the spring jars that come with liferay.

Answer (score 1):

You give an option yourself - duplicate classes. But without knowing how you build and what you're doing, there's hardly anything to do apart from asking you to make extra extra *extra* sure that you don't have duplicate resources on the classpath:

Check your deployed web application (once it's deployed to your application server) and its WEB-INF/lib folder for such duplicates. They might come in only during the buildprocess, e.g. they might not be in your IDE's workspace. Or Liferay might inject them (due to declared dependencies) during deployment.

You'll have to figure out how (and in which phase) those resources get there, then eliminate that option (e.g. through proper maven scope, e.g. "provided")